# Viewpager + DrawerLayout + NavigationView did not display correctly

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment_with_tab.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:background="@color/gitcafe_primary_color">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/gitcafe_primary_color"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <com.gitcafe.uibase.view.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I use `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(container, fragment).commit` to display the fragment, but the drawer did not display correctly like the pic.

How to fix this problem?

Screen shots:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/pD2Qn.png
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1beb.png

The second fragment in ViewPager is transparent, so we can see the drawer is under the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that happened since I've also have the same structure but never encountered that bug.

First make sure your `container` var is pointing to the correct container ID (I assume it is, though just to be sure).

Also try setting `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your DrawerLayout.